# How to setup django-fluent-comments on Django 1.6?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-1.6, django-fluent

I am trying to use [django-fluent-comments](https://github.com/edoburu/django-fluent-comments) along with Django 1.6. I tried following their github README tutorial for setting it up but some features like threaded comments and AJAX are not working.

my settings.py has this

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
        'fluent_comments',
        'crispy_forms',
        'django.contrib.comments',
        'threadedcomments',
)
COMMENTS_APP = 'fluent_comments'
```

urls.py has this

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^blog/comments/', include('fluent_comments.urls')),
)
```

my template post_details.html

```
<html>
{% load comments %}
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}fluent_comments/css/ajaxcomments.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>


<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}fluent_comments/js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}fluent_comments/js/ajaxcomments.js"></script>


{% render_comment_list for object %}
{% render_comment_form for object %}
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to see some the comments that I post. But the features that are not working are 
1) AJAX support, when I post a reply i get redirected to another page
2) Threaded comments, I simply do not see them.

How do I enable these features ?

Comment: It seems you've also asked us directly at https://github.com/edoburu/django-fluent-comments/issues/30 Did downgrading the jQuery version work?

Comment: ahh dont remember. I was concerned about other so things so I just shifted to disqus :D